# How can I set the AnyGantt 's Timeline Calendar

Tags: anychart

In the version 6 of AnyGantt (Flash), I could to define Non Working Days and Non Working Hours in calendar at Timeline, as you can see below...

(http://6.anychart.com/products/anygantt/docs/users-guide/index.html?calendar.html)

But now, I don´t know how can I define in my Gantt chart what are the Non Working Days.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this in the current version, but this feature is in the roadmap and will be available in version 7.10.0 version ETA: Apr'16.

http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/roadmap/

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any evidence that this has capability has been added. I am using AnyChart v7.11.0.1136. Anyone else figured this out?